# What is the difference between Apache Spark compute and slice?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I trying to make unit test on DStream.

I put data in my stream with a mutable queue `ssc.queueStream(red)`

I set the ManualClock to 0 
Start my streaming context.
Advance my ManualClock to batchDuration milis

When i'm doing a

```
stream.slice(Time(0), Time(clock.getTimeMillis())).map(_.collect().toList)
```

I got a result.

when I do

```
for (time <- 0L to stream.slideDuration.milliseconds + 10) {
      println("time "+ time + " " +stream.compute(Time(time)).map(_.collect().toList))      
    }
```

None of them contain a result event the `stream.compute(Time(clock.getTimeMillis()))`

So what is the difference between this two functions without considerings the parameters differences?

Answer (score 1):

Compute will return an RDD only if the provided time is a correct time in a sliding window i.e it's the zero time + a multiple of the slide duration.

Slice will align both the from and to times to slide duration and compute for each of them.

Comment: So how can you explain the result I have above ?

Comment: Actually if you used clock.getTimeMillis() instead of stream.slideDuration.milliseconds + 10 in the for loop, you should be getting some results.

Comment: clock.getTimeMillis() == stream.slideDuration.milliseconds, what is the différence between them ?

Answer (score 0):

In slide you provide time interval and from time interval as long as it is valid we generate Seq[Time]

```
def to(that: Time, interval: Duration): Seq[Time] = {
(this.milliseconds) to (that.milliseconds) by (interval.milliseconds) map (new Time(_))
```

}

and then we "compute" for each instance of Seq[Time]

```
 alignedFromTime.to(alignedToTime, slideDuration).flatMap { time =>
  if (time >= zeroTime) getOrCompute(time) else None
}
```

as oppose to compute we only compute for the instance of Time that we pass the compute method...